# How to change react element (li) with onClick to be strikethrough?

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to set element to become strikethrough when I click on it, but unfortunately I couldn't, nothing happens.

```
var UserList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            user: [],
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            createdAt: 0,
            isClicked: false,
        };
    },

handleOnClick: function() {
    var isClicked = this.state.isClicked;
    var style = {textDecoration: 'none'};
    if (isClicked === true) {
        style = {textDecoration: 'line-through'}
    }
 },

render: function() {

return (
    <div> 
        <Users user={this.state.user} onClick={this.handleOnClick}/>

    </div>
    );
```

Comment: how `Users` component looks like?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using 'style' anywhere once you set it in handleOnClick. You need to set some state or something.

Comment: You can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/36393/

Comment: Dodek you can see the answers but I think you need to change the way you look and think about a react application then it helps you a lot during your coding with react. The code you provide is look like a Jquery approach that you directly modify the DOM element when user do an action. Even if there was no issue in your approach still your code does not apply 'line-through' style to already checked element unless user click on them.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:
A similar example to yours:

```
const TodoItem = ({item, checkHandler}) => {

  const itemCheckHandler = () => {
    checkHandler (item.id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <li
        style={{
          textDecoration: item.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none',
        }}
        onClick={itemCheckHandler}
      >
        {item.text}
      </li>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and your `checkHandler` in your `App.js` where the state resides is like this (`items` bein an array of items):

```
  checkHandler = id => {
    this.setState ({
      items: this.state.items.map (item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          item.checked = !item.checked;
        }
        return item;
      }),
    });
  };
```

Don't try to change the style in a click handler. You should not change the style when a user does an action but rather do it at the time of it being rendered, that's the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Store the "strikethrough" value in a flag in the state and do it in the `render` function.

For example:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        ...
        isStrikeThrough: false,
        ...
    }
},

onHandleClick: function () {
    ....
    // toggle the strikethrough state
    this.setState({isStrikeThrough: !this.state.isStrikeThrough});
    ....
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <User
                user={this.state.user}
                strikeThrough={this.state.isStrikeThrough}
                onClick={this.handleOnClick}
            />
        </div>
    );
},
```

You haven't given any details about the `User` component, so the explanation above is based solely on what we have in the question. That said, there are a couple of ways in which this could be improved.

First, I'm assuming that you can add the strikethrough flag to the `User` component and render the `<strike>...</strike>` (or comparable CSS styles) there. That may or may not be true (ie. if the `User` component is a third-party component, it may be difficult to change it).

Second, the strikethrough state described above looks to me like it ought to be internal to the `User` component. If all you're doing is changing the markup in the `User` component based on a click on the `User` component, then the strikethrough code ought to be in the `User` component. And, perhaps more importantly, if the strikethrough is supposed to represent something important about the state of a user, something that should be saved as part of the user's state, then the strikethrough flag ought to be part of the user's state (and have a more informative name than `isStrikeThrough`).

Answer (score 1):

Dodek you can see the above answers but I think you need to change the way you look and think about a react application then it helps you a lot during your coding with react. The code you provided looks like a jQuery approach to me that you directly modify the DOM element when user do an action. Even if there was no issue in your approach still your code does not apply 'line-through' style to an already checked element which you get them from backend unless user clicks on an item.

You should look at your component as a very simple actor in a movie that accepts a very small set of parameters (compared to real word) and based on this input parameters it changes the way it appears in the frame. For example lets say you have a Todo item component (Like the one @Vennessa has provided here) in a vey simple case it accepts only an item text and also whether or not the item is checked;

These parameters may come from internal state or come from props or any other resources but in the end your component is accepting these parameters and all your internal logic that determines how your component should look must only rely and work with these params.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function Item(props){

const [clicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false); 

function handleClick(){
  setIsClicked((prevValue) => {
    return (!prevValue)
  });
}

return <li style={{textDecoration: clicked ? "line-through": "none" }} onClick={handleClick}> 

{props.text} </li>
}
```